# Gradle, Gradle wrapper different instances at Android Studio by ionic cordova

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I have a problem with Gradle. I can not use what I need. My personal case is. I am developing an Ionic based Android application. I added the Android platform, tried to compile the application. It asked Gradle. It was installed. The application was compiled successfully. To debug plugins the generated application was opened at Android Studio. It worked. Now it does not. I am confused about different Gradle and their wrappers. Why do they load from the network? It likes the Gradle loads Gradle... When I set exact instance of at Android Studio it shows another error. When I look for I see the global, Ionic, and build instances of Gradle and their wrappers. It seems I do not understand what is going...

Help to run the Android application at Android Studio that has been generated by Ionic Cordova.

Comment: Can you include the error you get? Do you have the Gradle downloaded and added to path? Or you are using the one that is bundled with the Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It does not disclose the real problem but It solves my issue.
I still use global/shared Gradle. The issue was that Gradle manipulated with Manifest.xml and could not resolve some data. So I removed minSdk, maxSdk from Manifest.xml, synced Gradle files at Android Studio, run compilation from Android Studio, it passed successfully.